# Box2D - many chain shapes efficiency

Tags: libgdx, box2d

I'm working at a game that creates terrain dynamically.
A terrain part is made by a body, with a chain shape, that has around 100-200 points. (so no problem with the 1k limit of Box2D), and is static.
The game has a collection of terrain parts.
Whenever I almost reach the end of the terrain, a new terrain part is added next to it.

Having like let's say, 50-100 terrain parts can be bad ?
My game is targeting mobile platforms only.

Should I destroy a terrain part from the Box2D world when the player is far away from it?
And create it back when he is close?

Thanks.

Comment: I bet box2d doesn't check for collision if body is far away from terrain part. All you need to do is not to render that part.

Comment: I do that, is pretty easy :D